# How to get entityManager by using an entity class

Tags: jpa, ejb

How to reach the entity manager which managed the entity. I mean; suppose that i have an entity reference in the sessionBean, how can i get entityManager of this entity belonged one?
I had already tried (plz see getEntityManagerOfEntity() method) contains method of em; but it does not work.

Thx
bgrds

```
@Stateless(name = "MainManager", mappedName = "MainManager")
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@Interceptors(value = { PerformanceMonitor.class, ProfileInterceptor.class })
public class MainManagerBean implements MainManager, MainManagerLocal
{
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "DSApp")
    private EntityManager manager;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "DSIX")
    private EntityManager integrationManager;

    @Resource
    SessionContext ctx;



public EntityManager getEntityManagerOfEntity(SuperEntity superEntity)
{
    if (manager.contains(superEntity))
        return manager;
    else if (integrationManager.contains(superEntity))
        return integrationManager;

    return null;
}



public SuperEntity findByPrimaryKey(SuperEntity superEntity)
{
    getEntityManagerOfEntity(superEntity).setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
    return dao.findByPrimaryKey(getEntityManagerOfEntity(superEntity), superEntity);
```

Comment: You can only do that on using vendor extensions. DataNucleus JPA provides *NucleusJPAHelper.getEntityManager(obj)* for example.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why do you want to do this? Could you shed more light on your use-case? You are not advised (officially AFAIR in JPA 2.0) to use EntityManager even from lifecycle methods.

Comment: i need it, thats why to make a generic method for multiple datasource. i try to union the crud methods inthrough stateles sessionbean which named in my project MainManagerBean. Thx 4 ur comments

Answer (score 2):

You cannot backtrack the `EntityManager` from an entity using the JPA API, even when it is still managed.

What you can do, if you have references to different EMs in your bean and the entity is managed, is to check the right EM by calling `em.contains(entity)`.

In most cases it is not really important to know, which EM has fetched an entity originally, since you can merge the entity into any persistence context and continue working with it.

Comment: Are you sure the entity really belongs to one of the entity managers? – Adam Dyga 3 hours ago
1 upvote
OP - please move this code to the question (update it). StackOverflow is not a bulletin board. – Piotr Nowicki 3 hours ago
  
  
And additional question to be answered: are you in the same transaction while you invoke this getEntityManagerOfEntity() function? Are you sure one of those EM should have your entity in managed state? – Piotr Nowicki 3 hours ago

Comment: Yes i am sure about entity belongs to one em.

Comment: Thankyou Mr Novicki for ur consideration. For now, it works as 2 spereate find method.one is findByPrimaryKeyWithinManager(entity), the other one is findByPrimaryKeyWithinIntegrationManager(entityIntegration). And thatsok in this situation. But,as i said; if i call getEntityManagerOfEntity inthrough findByPrimaryKey method. getEntityManagerOfEntity method returns null thats why false evaluation of if-clauses. May stateless sessionBean cause that issue(besides i see nothing about entities on em instance when i track during debug)?so,as i understood ur question; yes it's inthe same transaction.